# Regex for multiple replace of Colorcode

Tags: php, regex

i have prefixe for groupnames in a database, they consist of normal text and color codes eg.:
&c[&aAdmin&c]. The colorcodes start with an & and then one character or a number. they end on the next colorcode or the end of the string. 
There are no & as text in the string.
For now i have this function, but it only can handle one colorcode at the beginning of the string. any suggestions for a nice regex replace to handle multiple colorcodes in one string?

```
function mccolor($string){
$codes  = array(        "&0",
                        "&1",
                        "&2",
                        "&3",
                        "&4",
                        "&5",
                        "&6",
                        "&7",
                        "&8",
                        "&9",
                        "&a",
                        "&b",
                        "&c",
                        "&d",
                        "&e",
                        "&f");
$replace  = array(
                        '<span style="color:#000000;">',
                        '<span style="color:#0000BF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#00BF00;">',
                        '<span style="color:#00BFBF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#BF0000;">',
                        '<span style="color:#BF00BF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#BFBF00;">',
                        '<span style="color:#BFBFBF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#404040;">',
                        '<span style="color:#4040FF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#40FF40;">',
                        '<span style="color:#40FFFF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#FF4040;">',
                        '<span style="color:#FF40FF;">',
                        '<span style="color:#3F3F10;">',
                        '<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">');
return str_replace($codes, $replace, $string).'</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
function mccolor($m) {
    $trans = array(
        "&0"=>'#000000;',
        "&1"=>'#0000BF;',
        "&2"=>'#00BF00;',
        "&3"=>'#00BFBF;',
        "&4"=>'#BF0000;',
        "&5"=>'#BF00BF;',
        "&6"=>'#BFBF00;',
        "&7"=>'#BFBFBF;',
        "&8"=>'#404040;',
        "&9"=>'#4040FF;',
        "&a"=>'#40FF40;',
        "&b"=>'#40FFFF;',
        "&c"=>'#FF4040;',
        "&d"=>'#FF40FF;',
        "&e"=>'#3F3F10;',
        "&f"=>'#FFFFFF;',
    );
    return '<span style="color:'.$trans[$m[1]].'">'.$m[2].'</span>';
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/(&[0-9a-f])([^&]+|$)/', 'mccolor', '&c[&aAdmin&c]');
```

**output:**

```
<span style="color:#FF4040;">[</span><span style="color:#40FF40;">Admin</span><span style="color:#FF4040;">]</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like that:

```
$str = 'i have prefixe for groupnames in a database, they consist of normal text and color codes eg.: &c[&aAdmin&c]. The colorcodes start with an & and then one character or a number. &1they &2end &3on &4the &5next &0colorcode or the end of the string. There are no & as text in the string. For now i have this function, but it only can handle one colorcode at the beginning of the string. any suggestions for a nice regex replace to handle multiple colorcodes in one string?';

$colors = array(
"&0" => '<span style="color:#000000;">',
"&1" => '<span style="color:#0000BF;">',
"&2" => '<span style="color:#00BF00;">',
"&3" => '<span style="color:#00BFBF;">',
"&4" => '<span style="color:#BF0000;">',
"&5" => '<span style="color:#BF00BF;">',
"&6" => '<span style="color:#BFBF00;">',
"&7" => '<span style="color:#BFBFBF;">',
"&8" => '<span style="color:#404040;">',
"&9" => '<span style="color:#4040FF;">',
"&a" => '<span style="color:#40FF40;">',
"&b" => '<span style="color:#40FFFF;">',
"&c" => '<span style="color:#FF4040;">',
"&d" => '<span style="color:#FF40FF;">',
"&e" => '<span style="color:#3F3F10;">',
"&f" => '<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">'
);

echo preg_replace("#&([0-9a-f])#ie", '$colors["&" . \\1]', $str);
```

Comment: This will not put any `</span>` after text.